# Center of gravity of the photon beam

Tags: optics, photons, angular-momentum, singularities

I have a conceptual question:

In singular optics the orbital angular momentum (OAM) is represented by two components: intrinsic (no relation to spin!) and extrinsic. The first one is associated to optical vortex structure of the beam. The second one - to the trajectory of motion of the center of gravity of the light beam.

So, how can we define a center of gravity of a beam if photons are massless? Any suggestions/guesses/ideas/links are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so:

> Unfortunately, the word "mass" has been used in two different ways in physics. One was the way Einstein used it in E=mc^2, where mass is really just the same thing as energy (E) but measured in different units. This is the same "m" that you multiply velocity by to find momentum (p), and thus is sometimes called the inertial mass. It's also the mass that provides the source of gravitational effects. Light has this "m" because it has energy.

So basically, light has energy, which is really the same thing as mass according to Einstein's E=mc^2, and it is this that you use to calculate momentum.

There is a fuller explanation at https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=1424 (where I got the quote).

Good question, and I hope this explanation helps!